# I have embeded videos from youtube, how to click on any images to play video?

Tags: javascript, php

I have embedded videos from youtube, rightdisplay div shows the images of the videos. my code is playing video after clicking only first image. i want to know if i click on any image, the video should be played in the rightdisplay div. if i click on second or other images the video is not played.

```
$API_key = '';                                                                                                         
$maxResults = 10;
$api_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=video&q='.urlencode($query).'&maxResults='.$maxResults.'&key='.$API_key.'';
$videoList=json_decode(file_get_contents($api_url, true));


echo "<div class='left-display'>";

//$videodata = $videoList->items[0]->snippet->videoId;
  echo '<iframe id="play-video" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>';


//echo "<br>";
//$videotitle = $videoList->items[0]->snippet->title;
//echo $videotitle;

echo "</div>";


echo "<div class='right-display'>";
echo "<h4>Up Next</h4>";
foreach($videoList->items as $item)
{                                                                                                                     
  if(isset($item->id->videoId))
  {                                                                      
      echo '<div class="youtube-video">
            <div class="display">                                                                                                              
                <img id="image" width="240" height="150" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/'.$item->id->videoId.'/default.jpg" data="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$item->id->videoId.'">             
                <p>'. $item->snippet->title .'</p>
          </div>
        </div>'; 
  } 
}
echo "</div>";

?>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $('#image').click(function()
  {
    var value = $("#image").attr("data");
   $('#play-video').attr("src", value);

  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs have to be unique. You have multiple elements with ID `image`. Selecting `#image` gives you only the first because non-unique IDs aren't even valid. Use classes instead.

Also, in your click handler, you are yet again referring to a selector, so the attribute you get will be from the first element matching the selector and not from the one actually clicked. Use `this` instead.

---

So, to fix your issues, change `id="image"` to `class="image"` and change the Javascript code as explained:

```js
$('.image').click(function() {
  const value = $(this).attr('data')
  $('#play-video').attr('src', value)
})
```